# Java script to play a piano tune is not generating any sound?

Tags: javascript

I had chatgpt generate a piano tune and I asked it to wrap in javascript to be played in a browser. However, I can't seem to get the code to play anything? can someone help with this?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Piano Tune</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      // Create a new audio context
      const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

      // Define the notes and timing of the tune
      const notes = [
        { note: 'C4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'G4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'A4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'F4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'C4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'G4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'A4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'F4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'G4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'F4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'C4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'G4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'A4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'F4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'F4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'C4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'G4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'C4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'F4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'C4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'G4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'A4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'F4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'C4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'G4', time: 0.5 }
      ];

      // Function to play the tune
      async function playTune() {
        for (const { note, time } of notes) {
          const oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
          oscillator.frequency.value = note;
          oscillator.connect(audioContext.destination);
          oscillator.start();
          await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time * 1000));
          oscillator.stop();
        }
      }

      // Call the function to play the tune
      playTune();
    </script>
    
    song does not play 
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to ask ChatGPT to help with this problem?

Comment: @Kosh I did but it still failed. Poster below solved it by converting the notes to frequency. chatgpt does not know how to do this, yet. haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the note to a frequency, and start the song when they actually do something like click (or the browser will block it usually):

```js
function getFrequency(note) {
    var notes = ['A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#'],
        octave,
        keyNumber;

    if (note.length === 3) {
        octave = note.charAt(2);
    } else {
        octave = note.charAt(1);
    }

    keyNumber = notes.indexOf(note.slice(0, -1));

    if (keyNumber < 3) {
        keyNumber = keyNumber + 12 + ((octave - 1) * 12) + 1; 
    } else {
        keyNumber = keyNumber + ((octave - 1) * 12) + 1; 
    }

    // Return frequency of note
    return 440 * Math.pow(2, (keyNumber- 49) / 12);
};

      const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

      // Define the notes and timing of the tune
      const notes = [
        { note: 'C4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'G4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'A4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'F4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'C4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'G4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'A4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'F4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'G4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'F4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'C4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'G4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'A4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'F4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'F4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'C4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'G4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'C4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'F4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'C4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'G4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'A4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'F4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'C4', time: 0.5 },
        { note: 'G4', time: 0.5 }
      ];

      // Function to play the tune
      async function playTune() {
        for (const { note, time } of notes) {
          const oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
          oscillator.frequency.value = getFrequency(note);
          oscillator.connect(audioContext.destination);
          oscillator.start();
          await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time * 1000));
          oscillator.stop();
        }
      }

      // Call the function to play the tune
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', function() {
          playTune();
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Piano Tune</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<button id="start">Start</button>
    
    song does not play 
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, how did convert know how to convert the notes to frequency? is there a table somehwere I can look up?

Comment: @Ahdee it's a function, `getFrequency` which is provided right here in the post...